# Cloud Scheduler with multiple cron schedules?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Scheduler Job within Cloud Scheduler running to call a Cloud Function. Working as expected however I need to create multiple cron schedules for the same job, is this possible without recreating from scratch each one? There doesn't seem to be a Copy function.

Use Case:

```
Schedule 1 - Every 15 minutes Monday - Thursday
Schedule 2 - Every 15 minutes Friday SoD till Friday 22:00PM
Schedule 3 - Every 15 minutes Sunday 22:00PM till Sunday EoD
```

How can I achieve this, or do I just need to recreate all the schedules from scratch?

Comment: Do you want cron schedule expressions ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create all. but the tips when you want to repeat several time the same things is to script the creation. Either with gcloud or with terraform. Like this, the duplication and the creation/deletion are super easy and quick

Comment: Will it be possible for you to create them either through CLI (thus from shell script), or by using terraform? A side benefit - is an ability to store those files in some version management system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a Community Wiki as it's based on @GuillaumeBlaquiere and @Al-dann comments.

At this point you going to need to recreate all of those schedules from scratch, however, you can automate the creation of new Jobs with a script, either with gcloud or terraform. This will make duplication, creation and deletion of Jobs easier and quicker as well as allow you to version it.